# AWS RDS Postgres Force_ssl Param

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, spring-jdbc

I am working on connecting to AWS RDS Postgres through postgres java client. I have the rds.force_ssl parameter set to 1 in my new parameter group which is assigned to the rds instance.
I have rebooted my RDS DB instance.

While connecting via the java client, I would expect my connection to fail. But on the contrary, I'm able to connect to the rds postgres server.

I was expecting the connection to through an error.
Am I missing anything? is there a way to force the connections via SSL only?

Comment: What makes you think your Java client isn't using SSL?

Comment: I haven't imported any rds truststore jks certs, but still able to reach the server using the java client. Even while connecting via pgAdmin, I'm not providing any certs.
Expected the connection to fail in cases where the SSL certs are not provided.

Comment: You only have to import the trust store if you have certificate validation enabled on the connection. By default it will connect over SSL without validating the cert. It's different from how a web browser always validates certs on a website.